# Disable Node in CANoe using CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl

I am trying to disable a CAN node from sending messages. I have a function defined in CANoe:

```
long ILNodeControlStop(char aNodeName[])
```

When I try to use this in my CAPL script it shows type of parameters do not match. The error might be a very simple one, but I am not able to find it.

Suppose my node name is BECM. So I will use it as,

```
on start
{
   //some variables;
}

on key 'a'
{
   ILNodeControlStop(BECM);
}
```

This throws an error 'Type of parameters do not match'. Do I have to declare something in variables section ? (Using Node layer IL functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to the parameter type. It is not **dbNode**, it is char array.
So you have to pass it as a char array (string in common language).

```
ILNodeControlStop("BECM");
```

Also, consider using the ILStartSim(), ILStopSim() variants, check out their help and their availability.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it helped.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, please select it as the Answer for your question.